# Custom LinearLayout on camera preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, android-canvas, surfaceview

Scenario: 
I used surface view to create camera preview, then i create custom Linear Layout that contains text view,rating bar and button. I want to add the custom Linear Layout on the camera preview dynamically at run time.

This is my idea,i don't know whether it can be done or not, need opinions...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can overlay a SurfaceView which displays camera preview with text, buttons, or complex layouts.

Comment: can't find,any tutorial links,example project,hints,i am totally clueless

Comment: You checked this one: http://android-er.blogspot.de/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html?